# Insert a new row when Matched in Bigquery merge statement

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery

I have a use case where I want to perform MERGE operation on a BQ table but the catch is that for changes in a few columns of my target table I want to add a new row. Let's say uuid is the primary key and name is a column. But if name changes at any later time, I want to add a new row with the same uuid and new name. But apparently, BQ Merge allows new row insertion only when TARGET NOT MATCHED which means that a row with the said UUID wouldn't have existed. Is there any work around for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two temporary tables from your input:

- in the first you will have all new data without the existing records with new name
- in the second you will have the existing records with new name

Then, perform `MERGE` with the first and `INSERT` with the second.

Or alternatively, you can have one table with input data and add a new column - `isNameChanged`. You can populate performing `UPDATE` and `INNER JOIN` with the target table where

```
T.UUID  = S.UUID  AND T.name <> S.name
```

Then in your `MERGE` exclude records with `isNameChanged = 0`. Then, insert all records with `isNameChanged = 1`.